# issue with woocomerce meta data using ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I used the following code in my ionic 3 to print date as meta data. But it is not reflecting in my admin

I created a datetime in check out page, It accepts date entered by the user.

Now it should reflect in my woocommerce orders so I have sent the date using order meta. I could see the response in my console but it is not reflecting in the custom fields of woocommerce orders.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code snippet:

```
data.order_meta_data = {
    "shipping_date" : this.myDate,
    // key : "shipping_date", 
    // name: "shipping_date",
    //  value: this.myDate,
}
```

Comment: data.order_meta_data = {
                  "shipping_date" : this.myDate,
                  // key : "shipping_date", 
                  // name: "shipping_date",
                  //  value: this.myDate,
         
                        }
This is the code snippet

Comment: if you want to add any meta information with API then you have to register your field with the WooCommerce API. using the register_rest_field. Let me know your API endpoint and routes.

Comment: I used woocommerce rest API version v2. When I tried with legacy version wc-api/v3... it worked but when I used wc/v2, it is not... please help